# Composite and ScrolledComposite grab more space than necessary

Tags: java, swt

The following code snippet produces a Composite inside a ScrolledComposite. I also put a Label in it. A vertical Scrollbar is shwown, indicating that the composite grabs too much space.

```
@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    if (this.parent == null) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    parent.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    SashForm mainComposite = new SashForm(parent, SWT.NONE);
    mainComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    mainComposite.setLayoutData(gd);
//  createLeftSide(mainComposite);
    createRightSide(mainComposite);

//  mainComposite.setWeights(new int[] { 1, 4 });
}
```

The problem comes only in createRightSide:

```
private void createRightSide(Composite mainComposite) {
    ScrolledComposite detailsSC = new ScrolledComposite(mainComposite, SWT.SMOOTH | SWT.BORDER);
    GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    detailsSC.setLayoutData(gd);
    detailsSC.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

    Composite detailsComposite = new Composite(detailsSC, SWT.V_SCROLL);
    detailsComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
    detailsSC.setContent(detailsComposite);
    detailsSC.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    detailsSC.setExpandVertical(true);
    gd = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    detailsSC.setLayoutData(gd);

    Label dmyLabel = new Label(detailsComposite, SWT.NONE);
    GridData labelData = new GridData();
    dmyLabel.setLayoutData(labelData);
    dmyLabel.setText("Dummy");
```

When I don't use `SWT.FILL` for `mainComposite` the sub-composites don't fill the space.
`detailsComposite.getVerticalBar().setEnabled(false);` has no effect and `detailsSC.getVerticalBar()` returns null;
How can I tell the composite to not grab more space than necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I was able to replicate your exact case, but to me it seems that the scroll bar appears because you put the style `SWT.V_SCROLL` on the `detailsComposite` instead of the `ScrolledComposite` (`detailsSC`).

Also:

1. you are not setting the layout data to `detailsComposite` but twice to `detailsSC`
2. you are not setting the minimum size of the content in order for the `ScrolledComposite` to know when to show the scroll bar

This code should work:

```
private void createRightSide(Composite mainComposite) {
    ScrolledComposite detailsSC = new ScrolledComposite(mainComposite, SWT.SMOOTH | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    detailsSC.setLayoutData(gd);
    detailsSC.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));
    detailsSC.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    detailsSC.setExpandVertical(true);

    Composite detailsComposite = new Composite(detailsSC, SWT.NONE);
    detailsComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
    GridData gdd = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    detailsComposite.setLayoutData(gdd);

    Label dmyLabel = new Label(detailsComposite, SWT.NONE);
    GridData labelData = new GridData();
    dmyLabel.setLayoutData(labelData);
    dmyLabel.setText("Dummy");

    detailsSC.setContent(detailsComposite);       
    detailsSC.setMinSize(detailsComposite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
```